# WSDL Cannot find dispatch method for

Tags: soap, wsdl

For a web service call using a WSDL, I'm getting  the error `Cannot find dispatch method for {http://ws.somecompany.com/services}ValidateUser`, what does that mean exactly? Does it mean that it cannot find `ValidateUser`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This typically means that the SOAP framework could not find the operation that should be invoked via this request. A SOAP framework typically inspects the message to find pointers about how to route the message to the operation. Reasons for this error are mostly configuration issues (different namespaces, different encodings (RPC vs. doc/lit), usage of WS-Addressing vs. plain SOAP etc.)

Comment: If you are using Visual studio, here is a quick fix. Right click on the web service in Web References folder in Solution Explorer, choose Update web service. Wait for VS to complete the process and you are done

Comment: In my case the problem was that the `<element>` referenced in the `<part>` of the `<message>` which is referenced in the `<input>` of the `<operation>` did not have the same **namespace** as the `<operation>`. It also should have the same name to avoid wrapping of the input parameters.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem and struggling, googling for 1 day. But it was a simple mistake that instead of:

```
{http://ws.somecompany.com/services}ValidateUser
```

It should be

```
{http://ws.somecompany.com/services/}ValidateUser
```

I had not checked my WSDL clearly.

Comment: Yes, those are nasty. Also a common mistake is overlooking the difference between http and https in namespace URIs.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved by making sure that my config file either app.config or web.config depending on your client has correct endpoint. I had wrong address in my endpoint. I changed it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also lost a day to this issue, albeit with a different root cause.

In our case, two similar endpoint urls had got mixed up in the properties file. Both services were present and running, but the WSDLs didn't match up, so instead of a ConnectionException, we were getting this SOAPFaultException: "Cannot find dispatch method".

Answer (score 1):

My fifty cent, I got same error message but my case was yet different from all above, so hopefuly it might help someone.

I had .wsdl file, which got outdated without my knowledge when colleagues on the other side of ws renamed some element. Unfortunately, change was not visible when I compared .wsdl with theirs because .wsdl file had .xsd import which actually contained renamed element. After I found change, I updated my .xsd file and tada! error is gone and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following exception was throwing even I've supplied all the parameters

```
SoapFault exception: [S:Client] Cannot find dispatch method for {}parameters in
```

After banging my head few hours, just adding a \ while initializing SoapClient solved the problem.

From:

```
$client = new SoapClient($soapURL);
```

To:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($soapURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my .NET Application, In my case setting url same as "http://x-xxx-xx-xx-01:8080//TestProject/testproject?wsdl" (dummy url) solved the problem in the below code.

## Vb.Net

```
Dim rptGen as WSTestProject.testproject = Nothing
rptGen = New WSTestProject.testproject With {
        .Url = "http://x-xxx-xx-xx-01:8080//TestProject/testproject?wsdl",
        .Timeout = 1200000
        }
```

Here, WSTestProject is the WebService NameSpace and testproject is the web method.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a feign client for soap and I had the similar issue,Adding the correct namespace to the JAXB request and response object resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my environment was the wsdl cache in php. The updated wsdl was not picked by the client and it was referring to the old wsdl.

You can do either one of the following options when you do the development of the web service and test, as the wsdl change during the update/implementation of the web service

- Add `WSDL_CACHE_NONE` to soap client creation

  ```
  $myServices_client = new SoapClient($myServices_wsdl_URL, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );
  ```
- Set initialization parameter

  ```
  ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding '/' will work for you.
Error: Cannot find dispatch method for `{http://zzz.com}servicename`
Not Working Request: `xmlns:ser='http://zzz.com'>`
Working Request: `xmlns:ser='http://zzz.com/'>`

Answer (score 0):

I picked up an old Java project. I am not sure how it worked before, but I saw similar error and the reason was in wrong SOAP HTTP endpoint binding at server side.
Doesn't work:

```
Endpoint.create(HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING, servicePortType);
```

Works:

```
Endpoint.create(SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, servicePortType);
```