# Connecting to a .wsdl web service in android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I am new to android and I am developing an app that connects to a **wsdl** web service,

I have tried a number of tutorials but they are all a bit confusing and I end up getting errors. I easily did it using J2ME but I'm finding it difficult with android. I tried using **ksoap** and I ended up with and error like this:

```
06-05 12:34:42.634: W/System.err(387): 
SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Client' faultstring:'Cannot find dispatch method for 
{http://mobile.ws.web.bla.bla.com}
login' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Can anyone recommend any useful tutorials?

I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478406/wsdl-cannot-find-dispatch-method-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link [Create java based web service in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html) it will help you to create java based web service and if you have problem in that you can write me.