# Change a Delphi WSDL client definition to support different WDSLVersions

Tags: web-services, delphi, interface, wsdl, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to make implementations of new versions of a 3rd party WebService easier and simple.

For that I've change all WSDL generated classes to Interfaces with the same methods and properties.

Changed the service interface to a Generic one

And made a `AbstractFactory` to create the real products deppending on each version.

When all that was done, after solving other minor errors, I ran my tests I got:

> First chance exception at $75E5C42D. Exception class ERemotableException with message 'Cannot find dispatch method for {}consultarAlteracao'. Process intWSServidor.exe (7364)

There was a class `consultarAlteracao` and it becomes `IconsultarAlteracao`.

I've tried to change the `InvRegistry` and all other methods to use the interface and abstract classes, but no success on it.

Comment: That usually means the SOAP framework can not find the operation you are invoking. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478406/wsdl-cannot-find-dispatch-method-for) for some tips on solving it.

Comment: @GuillemVicens I've tried that. It was working before I change the inheritances to use the interfaces and factory methods

Comment: AFAIK, that `{}` means it is looking for the operation with `empty namespace`. Might it be that the `WSDL` has a specified namespace you're not considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ends up in Delphi does not supports interfaced elements as properies for TRemotable objects.

After change all properties to abstract classes that implements the basic interface everithing worked out fine